# Question about $\int_\Omega\!\cos^n\alpha\cdot\cos\theta_o\,d\omega_o$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I see this integral metioned in [this paper](http://mathinfo.univ-reims.fr/IMG/pdf/Using_the_modified_Phong_reflectance_model_for_Physically_based_rendering_-_Lafortune.pdf) (at the start of section 3.2 ,p.4)

$$\int_\Omega\!\cos^n\alpha\cdot\cos\theta_o\,d\omega_o$$

It's an integral over hemisphere and the $\alpha$ term means the angle between $\omega_o$ and certain specific direction. The paper indicates when $\alpha$ equals $\theta_o$ this integral will reach it's maximum that's 2$\pi$/(n+2). I want to ask why $\alpha$ equals $\theta_o$ make integral reach it's maximum and how to calculate the result 2$\pi$/(n+2), thanks.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable, make sure the edit is what you intended. Also, it seems (like Jonas said) there's an implicit interval missing in your question.

Comment: The interval is from 0~pi/2 and the expected result sould be 1/(n+2)

Comment: Can you post the exact question?

Comment: I try to refine my question and attach the source including this integral, hope this will make my question more clear, thanks all yours help.